# Integrating hundres of SOAP services - Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, soap, spring-integration, spring-ws

I have a system (kind of aggregator) that integrates with hundreds of different SOAP services - most of them do the same business functionality, but each service having different data structure in SOAP request & very few having 2 API calls to complete one transaction.

The present service integration workflow is

- create stubs from WSDL
- map data to the generated stub api
- setup a new endpoint to fire this api

I see this a repeated, unintelligent work & requires development effort for every new service integration.

Was there different approaches to integrate with lot many systems? Any libraries that can generate soap requests based on configurations, or I have to rely on some Java SOAP, Spring lirbaries to create custom SOAP xml request from my own configurations? I see Spring's `WebServiceGatewaySupport` for webservice client but requires stubs created from wsdl?

Is it wise to define soap request xml as templates for every service, generate xml with input data?

Other ways I thought was to develop each integrations as independent microservice layered under an API gateway that routes each requests to specific service. But this design approach will have hundreds of services running, consuming more resources (in case of `Spring boot`).

Generate stubs & deposit the jar to disk, load this jar with a classloader & use the stubs using reflection - not so simple, I believe.

Use of serverless looks promising but is not possible immediately.

Comment: There is no other way than have some transformation from common model to specific for particular service and back. Since you have mentioned Spring Integration in tag, I would really recommend to make you familiar with that project: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration

Comment: Yes, so, which way do you think such transformation logic be written? Read from spec and generate soap request? Xml Templates? Code using integration libraries?

Comment: I would generate JaxB model from WSDL and use JaxBMarshaller for calling WebServices